# Why does Pascal VOC 2007 dataset have almost 2500 images for 'train' and same number for 'val'? Val should have less images

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, yolo

PS :  I am following this https://github.com/lvaleriu/ssd_keras-1 to train ssd300* on pascal voc 2007 dataset only. But the val loss is not going below 5.

1. Isn't it wrong in PASCAL VOC 2007 dataset to have same number of train & val images, whereas ideally, val images must be less. Or am I making a mistake?
2. After training for 67 epochs on ssd300, I get val loss around 5 which is not going down and maP is around 70%. Should I stop here? I have seen in tutorials that val loss under 1 is desired. What's the relation in val loss and map?

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.  Please don't ask us to explain why your neural network isn't working as well as you had hoped; it's not our role to debug/diagnose your code, and in any case, since you have told us very little about what you are doing, we don't really have very much to go on.  Finally, you seem to believe/assume that the validation set should have fewer images, but it's not clear to me where that belief came from.  There is no such rule.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/34413/8560, https://stackoverflow.com/q/51312641/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 2):

The size of your validation matters only for the precision of your validation score. Every sample in your validation has some score for validation. The main goal is to be able to say how well your model generalized to unseen samples. Because the total score over the validation set is usually the mean over all the samples, the variance goes down if you have more samples. This can be seen from the central limit theorem.

The downside of adding more validation samples is that you reduce the amount of training data that you have. In this case this is a fairly big cost, given that the total set of labeled data is not that big. In this case you have to make a trade off, where more training data will lead to a better model but you will be less sure about how much better and it makes it more difficult to compare different models/settings with each other. Another approach could be cross validation, where you sample new test sets a number of times, allowing you to have a bigger training set and still use a higher number for validation. This has the downside of being much more computationally expensive.

With regards to your second question, usually losses are correlated but not 1 to 1 translateable, and depends on the case. You cannot say directly how they relate in this case (also you did not specify which loss you are optimizing for).